# definitively determine the primary physical LAN port (device0)

Tags: windows, powershell, network-adapter

Is the device with the lowest DeviceID a reliable way to find the first LAN port on a machine with 2 ports?

I have been searching for a way to deterministically get the first LAN port across our servers of similar, but varying hardware. I have not seen anything that confirms the left or right port will always be device 0 or 1.  I'm guessing that the left device will (almost) always be the first hardware port, and the right is the second, however I think this is just convention and not a guarantee.

The answer I've come across is to set a manual metric value for each of the adapters, but this is a software config approach.  While this seems like a reasonable answer for new machines, I still have to make sure machines that are already deployed out in the world will behave predictably so our non-technical clients can always plug into the same port.

This powershell script seems to do what I want, but maybe I just haven't found a test machine where this isn't true.

```
#get only the physical network adapters
#the device with the lowest DeviceID is the primary
$netAdapters = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | ?{$_.PhysicalAdapter} | ?{$_.Name -notlike 'Microsoft*'}
Write-Host($netAdapters | Format-table | Out-String)
```

Comment: There's no guarantee of correlation between the physical location of a port and a device ID. This is similar to the idea of which port on a video card will be the primary port - varies from card to card.  I've seen quad-port NICs with the ports in 1-3-2-4 order.  And what about a system with multiple NIC cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could indeed vary by manufacturer, and even NIC/Motherboard model. Most likely, you'll have to inspect the NIC/Motherboard yourself to see what the port IDs are (and even then, you're not guaranteed that they'll be printed). The most fool-proof way to be sure is to only connect one of the ports, then check the system and see which interface is reporting as up.